# Visual Basic NET cant connect to TLS 1.2 web server

Tags: python, visual-studio, tls1.2

I need to connect to local web server with Visual Basic NET. Web server have TLS 1.2. First i need to connect to page with username and password and than i need to take some values from page that will be open. I know that everything is ok with server because i can connect with python script. So, Visual Basic code that do not work is:

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Net.Http
Imports Newtonsoft.Json


Public Class Main

    Dim Red As Integer

    Private Shared ReadOnly client As HttpClient
    Public Function AcceptAllCertificates(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal certification As System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate, ByVal chain As System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain, ByVal sslPolicyErrors As System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors) As Boolean
        Return True
    End Function

    Shared Sub New()
        client = New HttpClient()
    End Sub

    Private Function GetSessionID() As String
        Dim form As MultipartFormDataContent = New MultipartFormDataContent()
        form.Add(New StringContent("Login"), "login")
        form.Add(New StringContent("Username"), "user")
        form.Add(New StringContent("Pasword"), "pwd")

        Try
            Dim response As HttpResponseMessage = client.PostAsync("main.app", form).Result

            Dim content As String = response.Headers.GetValues("Set-Cookie").FirstOrDefault()
            Dim parts() As String = content.Split(";")
            Dim value As String = parts(0)

            If value.Substring(0, 9) = "SessionId" Then
                Return value.Substring(10)
            End If
        Catch exception As Exception

        End Try

        Throw New Exception("Can't find the session ID")
    End Function

    Private Function GetTimeStamp() As Integer
        Return DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(New DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalSeconds()
    End Function

    Private Sub GetValue(ByVal sessionID As String)
        Dim response As HttpResponseMessage = client.GetAsync("ajax.app?SessionId=" & sessionID & "&service=getDp&plantItemId=00000&_=" & GetTimeStamp()).Result

        Dim data = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result, New With {Key .value = "", .unit = ""})

        Text1.Text = data.value & " " & data.unit
    End Sub

    Private Sub Connect_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Connect.Click
        Try
            Dim sessionID As String = GetSessionID()

            txtSessionID.Text = sessionID
            GetTemperature(sessionID)
        Catch exception As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(exception.ToString())
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub Main_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = AddressOf AcceptAllCertificates

        'ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12

        client.BaseAddress = New Uri("https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/)

    End Sub
```

And the Python code that work is:

```
import requests

urllib3 = requests.urllib3 
urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)

session = requests.session()
session.verify=False

response = session.get('https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/main.app?user=Username&pwd=Password')
response = session.get('https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/ajax.app?service=getDp&plantItemId=00000&_=')

print(response.text)
```

Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 0):

.Net has a setting called “useStrongCrypto” that allows the client PC to use TLS 1.1 and higher.  By default it is turned off for some frustrating reason.

To enable your local client to use TLS 1.1 and higher (or as Microsoft terms it “strong crypto”) you need to edit the following registry entries:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft.NETFramework\v4.0.30319\SchUseStrongCrypto = 00000001
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft.NETFramework\v4.0.30319\SchUseStrongCrypto = 00000001

This will need to be done for each version of the .NET Framework that you have installed.  They should each have a registry entry in the last tree.  Don't forget to reboot for the changes to take affect and take a backup of the registry first.

Here is more information: https://dougrathbone.com/blog/2016/02/28/pci-compliant-web-deploy-getting-webdeploy-working-after-disabling-insecure-ciphers-like-ssl-30-and-tls-10

Comment: Hi Matt L. Thank you for the answer. I edit this registry for all NET Framework versions. But it do not work and i receive this exception:

https://ibb.co/WgT9RW1

The address is correct. I do not know why is this happen. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try uncommenting the line ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12  I have other code that uses this exact statement and it worked for me.

Comment: I tried but not help. Can you send me your code that work so i will only change for my need? Thank you in advance.